# Capture all screen with a mouse

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm trying to capture all screen in explorer with a mouse. My code is:

```
x = Browser("Main").Page("SubMain").GetROProperty("x")
y = Browser("Main").Page("SubMain").GetROProperty("y") 
width = Browser("Main").Page("SubMain").GetROProperty("width")
height = Browser("Main").Page("SubMain").GetROProperty("height")

Set obj = CreateObject("mercury.devicereplay")
obj.MouseClick x+5, y+50,RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON

obj.DragAndDrop  x+5, y+50, x + width, y + height, 0

Set obj = Nothing
```

The mouse does moves but not clicking.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

*3706* is "*Provider not found*" indicating the OraOLEDB redistributable is not installed on your system. Download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/utilsoft-088126.html).

Comment: But wait, maybe when i put strProviderName its not suposed to be OraOLEDB.Oracle? Or is it the same name in every program?

Comment: It's correct for Oracle + OLEDB: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/